# Importing data in chunks/batches from flat file into sql table using C#

Tags: sql-server, loading, chunks

I want to load chunks/batches of data into a SQL table from a FLAT FILE that contains a lot of data (in TERABYTES).

I want to load chunks of data, i.e like 1-10000,10001-20000, (...) , into staging table as the memory is limited for the staging tables.
Once the data is loaded into staging table i want to load the data into final table.

Can some one suggest some C# script where I can provide **FROM ID** number to **TO ID** number as variables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past.  Here is the rough syntax.  This is for Sql to Sql.  See link at bottom on how to use ODBC to query a text file instead.

```
        int Start = 1;
        int End = 10000;
        using (SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection())
        {
            string Sql = $"Select * From Table Where Id Between {Start} and {End}";
            SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(Sql);
            SqlDataReader reader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(SqlCon);
            bulk.DestinationTableName = "StagingTable";
            bulk.WriteToServer(reader);
        }
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/accessing-text-files-using-odbc-data-provider/

Comment: Hi @Joe C, Thanks for the reply.
But, it would be more helpful for me if some one can suggest some work around or provide some script with which i should read limited number of records from the flat file (i mean like 1-1000) and load them to sql table and again in next time if i want (1001-3000) and load them to sql table.
Note that i have very limited space in staging table so i need to load only limited records and load them to final table next time.
kindly, some one help me in providing this requirement in ssis / ssis script component

Comment: You could use this script in SSIS.